# Create JSON object from XML with an array of size 1

Tags: java, json, xml

I want to create `JSON` from `XML`.
For that I'm using [toJSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/XML.html#toJSONObject(java.lang.String)) of `org.json.XML`.

In the doc it says:

> Sequences of similar elements are represented as JSONArrays

So the `XML`

> < element1>1< /element1>
>   < element1>2< /element1>

will be transformed into `JSONArray` with size 2, but the `XML`

> < element1>1< /element1>

will be transformed into `JSONObject`.
I want it to be transformed into `JSONArray` of size 1.

Is there a way to do that? (manually / using the API)
I have the paths of the lists predefined.

Comment: How should it know when to create an array of size 1 and when not?

Comment: Let's say I know the paths of the lists

Comment: You could replace the objects with arrays manually.